# Particle decay, decay rate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, scattering

I have a questions about the article [Particle decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_decay) two-body decay.

$$|\vec{p}_1| = |\vec{p}_2| = \frac{[(M^2 - (m_1 + m_2)^2)(M^2 - (m_1 - m_2)^2)]^{1/2}}{2M}$$

$$(M, \vec{0}) = (E_1, \vec{p}_1) + (E_2, \vec{p}_2)$$

In spherical coordinates

$$d^3 \vec{p} = |\vec{p}\,|^2\, d|\vec{p}\,|\, d\phi\, d\left(\cos \theta \right)$$

I wanted to know how using delta function to perform $d^3\vec{p_{2}}$ and $d |\vec{p_{1}}|$ was calculated $d\Gamma$, which is equal to

$$d\Gamma = \frac{ \left| \mathcal{M} \right|^2}{32 \pi^2}  \frac{|\vec{p}_1|}{M^2}\, d\phi_1\, d\left( \cos \theta_1 \right)$$

How then integrate to calculate decay width $\Gamma$?
I'll be grateful for step by step explanation.

Comment: Could you please show us the calculation you're asking about? Ideally, by editing it into your question as MathJax; failing that, by linking to it or including a screenshot, but those options are less than ideal because they don't make this question appear in relevant searches going forward.

Comment: Each delta function gives you one integral 'for free'. You just set the value of one of the variables you've got to integrate over to the value (in terms of other variables and constants) prescribed for it by the delta function.

Comment: [PDG](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/reviews/rpp2018-rev-kinematics.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a straight plug-in! Hint: Your text *must* have taught you how to evaluate the Lorentz-invariant phase space, of course. The rightmost-hand side of your top equation is what the energy conservation constraint dictates, a number, let's call it *a*.

Integrate $\vec p_2$ out given its δ-function, and call $|\vec p_1|=p$, and utilize $E_i=\sqrt{m^2_i+ p^2}\leadsto E'_i=p/E_i(p)$ to [transform the energy δ-function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/511857/delta-function-of-a-curve), mindful of your $E_1(a)+E_2(a)=M$,
$$
 {d\phi_1 d\cos (\theta_1) \over 16 \pi^2 }\int\!\!dp~~p^2 {\delta (E_1(p)+E_2(p)-M)\over E_1 E_2} \\ = {d\phi_1 d\cos (\theta_1) \over 16 \pi^2 }\int\!\! dp~~a {\delta (p-a)\over E_1(a)+ E_2(a)}= 
 {d\phi_1 d\cos (\theta_1)\over 16 \pi^2 }~~ { a\over  M}.
$$