# Manipulation of functions inside a Dirac Delta function

Tags: mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions

[image]

It is not clear to me how this derivation proceeds through the steps. Could someone help me understand how to arrive at this result or point me towards a resource that explains these algebraic manipulations within the Dirac Delta function?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Apologies, not sure how I forgot to mention that P is the primitive function/antiderivative of p.

For context this is related to the Sudakov veto algorithm used in generating parton showers.

Comment: Don't use screenshots and images for math. Use MathJax instead.

Comment: I guess you just want us to *guess* the relationship between $P$ and $p$? Or what?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Properties

Comment: Which reference? Which page?

Comment: What is $\rho$? According to naturallyInconsistent’s answer $\int_0^1d\rho=1$, but you never mentioned that.

Comment: Related : [Physical meaning of the Jacobian in relation to Dirac delta function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/371700/physical-meaning-of-the-jacobian-in-relation-to-dirac-delta-function/371706#371706).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty grotesque.

You need to first know a property of the Dirac delta distribution. It is stated as
$$\tag1\delta[g(x)]=\frac{\delta(x-x_0)}{|g^\prime(x_0)|}$$
on Wikipedia, say, for any function $g$ that has a simple isolated root at $x_0$, and we will be using this property in reverse for many times.

---

There are many skipped steps, even at the front.
$$
\begin{align}
\tag21&=\int_0^1\mathrm d\rho\\
\tag3 &=\int_0^1\mathrm d\rho\int\mathrm dt\ \delta(t-c)
\end  {align}
$$
where the integral of $t$ just needs to include $c$; it is then sensible to choose any $c$ we like, which is in particular $c=P^{-1}[P(u)+\ln\rho]$ that the text used.

We can now apply the property above backwards twice, once on the CDF function $P$ and another time on the exponential $\mathrm e$, leading to the 2nd to last line. By the FTC, $P(t)-P(u)=-\int_t^u p(x)\mathrm dx$

The last line is then a swapping of the integrals, since we are free to use the Dirac delta distribution to destroy $\rho$ rather than $t$, and to do that properly, you also have to consider the integration region.

Comment: Thank you very much. The one question I have left is if you could expand on how you get the limits 0->u on the last integral?